# Do these sentences make sense?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I want to know these sentences below make sense.
And what part of the sentence is wrong.

1. The senator urged a tax cut.
2. The senator urged for the tax cut.
3. The senator urged against the tax cut.
4. I urged him to turn to Christ and commit his life to him.

Answer (score 0):

When "urge" is used as a transitive verb, the object is usually a person that you are trying to persuade.

Your 4th sentence is a good example of this: "him" is the object of the transitive verb, and the prepositional phrase in the rest of the sentence describes what you are persuading him to do.

Your 1st sentence is incorrect, because the object (tax cut) is not a person you are trying to persuade. Your 2nd sentence is the correct way to fix the 1st sentence if there is no object. You could include an object as follows:

> The senator urged his colleagues to approve the tax cut.

The 2nd and 3rd sentences are correct uses of "urge" as an intransitive verb. The prepositional phrases after "urge" describe the matters that the senator is pushing for/against.